No /odom and /cmd_vel topics with diff_drive plugin
I am new to ROS2 and am currently working on getting a basic simulation going using Gazebo/ROS2 Humble. My robot's urdf works as expected on rviz when I use joint state publisher to control the wheels. However, when I try using the differential drive plugin rviz doesn't seem to work properly. I don't see the /odom or /cmd_vel topics on ros topic list, and I also don't see the diff_drive node on rqt_graph. I believe this is why the wheels of my robot on rviz aren't working correctly.
There was another very similar question but even when I implemented that I had the same issue as before. I don't believe that it is related to formatting or wrongly naming any tags (outside of the plugin's gazebo tags) since everything works when I run it using joint state publisher.
Question - Why are the /odom and /cmd_vel topics, and the diff_drive node not showing up, and is this why the wheels are not showing up correctly on rviz?
my_robot.urdf.xacro - Main urdf file that I reference in the launch file

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="my_robot" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <xacro:include filename="common_properties.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="mobile_base.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="mobile_base_gazebo.xacro" />

</robot>

mobile_base.xacro - Creates links and joints
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <xacro:property name="base_length" value="0.6" />
    <xacro:property name="base_width" value="0.4" />
    <xacro:property name="base_height" value="0.2" />
    <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.1" />
    <xacro:property name="wheel_length" value="0.05" />

    <link name="base_footprint" />

    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${base_length} ${base_width} ${base_height}" />
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${base_height / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <material name="blue" />
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${base_length} ${base_width} ${base_height}" />
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${base_height / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
        </collision>
        <xacro:box_inertia m="5.0" l="${2*base_length}" w="${2*base_width}" h="${2*base_height}"
                       xyz="0 0 ${base_height / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </link>

    <xacro:macro name="wheel_link" params="prefix">
        <link name="${prefix}_wheel_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_length}" />
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi / 2.0} 0 0" />
                <material name="grey" />
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_length}" />
                </geometry>
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi / 2.0} 0 0" />
        </collision>
        <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="1.0" r="${2*wheel_radius}" h="${2*wheel_length}" 
                                xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi / 2.0} 0 0" />
        </link>
    </xacro:macro>

    <xacro:wheel_link prefix="right" />
    <xacro:wheel_link prefix="left" />

    <link name="caster_wheel_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <sphere radius="${wheel_radius / 2.0}" />
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <material name="grey" />
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="${wheel_radius / 2.0}" />
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        </collision>
        <xacro:sphere_inertia m="0.5" r="${2*wheel_radius / 2.0}"
                              xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </link>

    <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_footprint" />
        <child link="base_link" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${wheel_radius}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="base_right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="right_wheel_link" />
        <origin xyz="${-base_length / 4.0} ${-(base_width + wheel_length) / 2.0} 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>

    <joint name="base_left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="left_wheel_link" />
        <origin xyz="${-base_length / 4.0} ${(base_width + wheel_length) / 2.0} 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>

    <joint name="base_caster_wheel_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="caster_wheel_link" />
        <origin xyz="${base_length / 3.0} 0 ${-wheel_radius / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>

</robot>

mobile_base_gazebo.xacro
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <gazebo reference="base_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="right_wheel_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="left_wheel_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="caster_wheel_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
        <mu1 value="0.1" />
        <mu2 value="0.1" />
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="diff_drive" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
            <ros>
                <!--<namespace>/</namespace>-->
            </ros>

            <update_rate>30</update_rate>

            <!-- wheels -->
            <left_joint>base_right_wheel_joint</left_joint>
            <right_joint>base_left_wheel_joint</right_joint>

            <!-- kinematics -->
            <wheel_separation>0.45</wheel_separation>
            <wheel_diameter>0.2</wheel_diameter>

            <!-- limits -->
            <max_wheel_torque>20</max_wheel_torque>
            <max_wheel_acceleration>1.0</max_wheel_acceleration>

            <command_topic>cmd_vel</command_topic>

            <!-- output -->
            <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
            <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
            <publish_wheel_tf>true</publish_wheel_tf>

            <odometry_topic>odom</odometry_topic>
            <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
            <robot_base_frame>base_footprint</robot_base_frame>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

</robot>

Launch File
<launch>
    <let name="urdf_path" value="$(find-pkg-share my_robot_description)/urdf/my_robot.urdf.xacro" />
<let name="rviz_config_path" value="$(find-pkg-share my_robot_bringup)/rviz/urdf_config.rviz" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" exec="robot_state_publisher">
        <param name="robot_description" value="$(command 'xacro $(var urdf_path)')" />
    </node>

    <include file="$(find-pkg-share gazebo_ros)/launch/gazebo.launch.py">
 <arg name="world" value="$(find-pkg-share my_robot_bringup)/worlds/test_world.world" />
    </include>

    <node pkg="gazebo_ros" exec="spawn_entity.py" args="-topic robot_description -entity my_robot" />

    <node pkg="rviz2" exec="rviz2" output="screen" args="-d $(var rviz_config_path)" />
</launch>

Rviz error

ROS2 topic list and rqt_graph


Is the plugin loaded correctly? Any console outputs, and is the plugin shown in the gazebo UI?

@ChristophFroehlich I don't see any console outputs other than what is shown when I run the launch file (rviz error image). The plugin shows up on Gazebo, so I believe it is loaded correctly. I didn't do anything to load the plugin other than include the gazebo tag for diff drive in mobile_base_gazebo.xacro, not sure if there was something else that needed to be done.

I was able to find a fix. During my ROS2 setup I had apparently never installed gazebo plugins:
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-gazebo-plugins

So, although the diff_drive node showed up on gazebo under the robot model, the plugin was never installed.
